# Add url to API response on serializers.Serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a django-application with the followin files

**models.py**

```
from datetime import datetime

class Comment(object):
    def __init__(self, email, content, created=None):
        self.email = email
        self.content = content
        self.created = created or datetime.now()
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()
    url = serializers.CharField(source='get_absolute_url', read_only=True)
```

in views.py I now define a a ViewSet to return the serialized results. In this class I define a list of comments

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import *
from .models import Comment
from rest_framework.response import Response


class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    lc = [Comment(email='jan@auto.com', content='hallo mike'),
          Comment(email='jan@auto.com', content='hallo jan'),
          Comment(email='jan@auto.com', content='hallo niklas')]

    def list(self, request):
        serializer = CommentSerializer(self.lc, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        user = self.lc[int(pk)]
        serializer = CommentSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

When I now call the api (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments/?format=json`) I get the following result

```
[
  {
    "email": "jan@auto.com",
    "content": "hallo mike",
    "created": "2019-08-16T16:53:56.371890Z"
  },
  {
    "email": "jan@auto.com",
    "content": "hallo jan",
    "created": "2019-08-16T16:53:56.371890Z"
  },
  {
    "email": "jan@auto.com",
    "content": "hallo niklas",
    "created": "2019-08-16T16:53:56.371890Z"
  }
]
```

In this response I would have hoped to see a url for each dataset. The error ist probably thats for `url = serializers.CharField(source='get_absolute_url', read_only=True)` the source is undefined in the `Comment` class. However I have no clue how to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *define* a [**`get_absolute_url`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) on your model, like:

```
# app/models.py

from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Comment(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    content = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('name-of-view', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Here *`'name-of-view'`* is the name of the view you defined, for example in your `urls.py`, and the `kwargs=...` is given a dictionary that maps the values for the corresponding URL path parameters.

Comment: thanks for the response. However since my class is not working with the django db I did not inherit my `class Comment` from `model.Model` but from `object`. Is ist possible to get the url for an object not on the db?

Comment: @jan-seins: then how do you *persist* comments? You can define `get_absolute_url` on the object as well, there is nothing that enforces it to be a model, but a lot of Django functionality will not work for non-models.